# Create and append 2 columns to dataframe via custom function - Python 3.x

Tags: python, pandas

I have a dataframe called `csv_table` that looks like this:

```
      class                      ID                                               text
0         2  BIeDBg4MrEd1NwWRlFHLQQ  Decent but terribly inconsistent food. I've ha...
1         4  NJHPiW30SKhItD5E2jqpHw  Looks aren't everything.......  This little di...
2         2  nnS89FMpIHz7NPjkvYHmug  Being a creature of habit anytime I want good ...
3         2   FYxSugh9PGrX1PR0BHBIw  I recently told a friend that I cant figure ou...
4         4  ScViKtQ2xq6i5AyN4curYQ  Chevy's five years ago was crisp and fresh and...
5         2  vz8Q37FSlypZlgy5N7Ym0A  Every time I go to this Jack In The Box I get ...
6         4   OJuG2EvItSZXbu8KowI9A  I've been going to Cluckers for years. Every t...
7         4   k9ci6SfI5RZT3smNdnvSg  .                                             ...
8         4  qq6bQbrBZyd4lOBd8KSCoA  Well, after their remodel the place no longer ...
9         4     FldFfwfuk9T8kvkp8iw  Beer selection was good, but they were out of ...
10        4  63ufCUqbPcnl6abC1SBpvQ  Ihop is my favorite breakfast chain, and the s...
11        4   nDYCZDIAvdcx77EcmYz0Q  A very good Jewish deli tucked in and amongst ...
12        4  uoC1llZumwFKgXAMlDbZIg  Went here for lunch with Rand H. and this plac...
13        2   BBs1rbz75dDifvoQyVMDg  Picture the least attractive person you'd sett...
14        4    2t9znjapzhioLqb4Pf1Q  Really really really strong Margaritas!   The ...
15        4  GqLgixGcbWh51IzkwsiswA  I would not have known about this place had it...
```

`[1999 rows x 3 columns]`

I am trying to add `2` columns to the `csv_table`, one that specifies the number of words in the `text` column (as denoted with a "word" being a split on space), and a column that specifies the number of "clean" words as defined by a custom function.

I have the ability to count the *total* clean and dirty words, but how can I apply these functions to each row in the dataframe, and append those columns?

Code is below:

```
import nltk, re, pandas as pd
from nltk.corpus import stopwords
import sklearn, string
import numpy as np
from sklearn.neural_network import MLPClassifier
from sklearn import preprocessing
from sklearn.preprocessing import MinMaxScaler
from sklearn.model_selection import train_test_split
from sklearn.svm import SVC
from sklearn.neighbors import KNeighborsClassifier
from sklearn.ensemble import RandomForestClassifier
from itertools import islice

# This function removes numbers from an array
def remove_nums(arr): 
    # Declare a regular expression
    pattern = '[0-9]'  
    # Remove the pattern, which is a number
    arr = [re.sub(pattern, '', i) for i in arr]    
    # Return the array with numbers removed
    return arr

# This function cleans the passed in paragraph and parses it
def get_words(para):   
    # Create a set of stop words
    stop_words = set(stopwords.words('english'))
    # Split it into lower case    
    lower = para.lower().split()
    # Remove punctuation
    no_punctuation = (nopunc.translate(str.maketrans('', '', string.punctuation)) for nopunc in lower)
    # Remove integers
    no_integers = remove_nums(no_punctuation)
    # Remove stop words
    dirty_tokens = (data for data in no_integers if data not in stop_words)
    # Ensure it is not empty
    tokens = [data for data in dirty_tokens if data.strip()]
    # Ensure there is more than 1 character to make up the word
    tokens = [data for data in tokens if len(data) > 1]

    # Return the tokens
    return tokens 

def main():

    tsv_file = "filepath"
    csv_table=pd.read_csv(tsv_file, sep='\t')
    csv_table.columns = ['class', 'ID', 'text']

    print(csv_table)

    s = pd.Series(csv_table['text'])
    new = s.str.cat(sep=' ')
    clean_words = get_words(new)
    dirty_words = [word for word in new if word.split()]
    clean_length = len(clean_words)
    dirty_length = len(dirty_words)
    print("Clean Length: ", clean_length)
    print("Dirty Length: ", dirty_length)


main()
```

Which currently produces:

```
Clean Length:  125823
Dirty Length:  1091370
```

I did try `csv_table['clean'] = csv_table['text'].map(get_words(csv_table['text']))` which yielded:

`AttributeError: 'Series' object has no attribute 'lower'`

**How can I apply the dirty / clean logic to each row and append those two columns to the dataframe?**

Comment: Generally if you have a function `myFunc` that takes one cell's data and return the result you need, you can do `df['new_col'] = df['text'].map(myFunc)` and it will give you in `new_col` the result of the function for each row.

Comment: How is it I can do that but then add it back to this dataframe, is there example you can post? @Aryerez

Comment: When you'll do that, you will have a new column named 'new_col' in your dataframe. If you want to replace the existing 'text' column, do `df['text'] = df['text'].map(myFunc)`

Comment: I don't want to replace the existing column. I'm also confused as to what I'm supposed to pass to `get_words`, as passing `csv_table['text']` passes the entire column...not just the row

Comment: In fact, `csv_table['clean'] = csv_table['text'].map(get_words(csv_table['text']))` is an error

Comment: Inside `map()` don't pass the column as a parameter for the function, but only the function name, as I wrote.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Use [`apply`](https://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/reference/api/pandas.DataFrame.apply.html) to apply a function on each row.
For the dirty word count you can split the strings with pandas and then apply `len` to get the count. For the clean word count, directly apply the custom function:

```
csv_table['dirty'] = csv_table['text'].str.split().apply(len)
csv_table['clean'] = csv_table['text'].apply(lambda s: len(get_words(s)))
```

Comment: You have to `.apply(len)` to the second row as well.

Comment: @jorijnsmit: You are correct, I erroneously assumed that was what `get_words` returned.